# want to do activity based on radio button of another class in android

Tags: android, class, android-intent, radio-button

i have 3 class namely first , second and third. first class has a radio group. but that has nothing to do on that class,where as in the case of class second and third it has some activity to do. how i can check that radio buttons of first class from second and third classes and how do activity based on this..?

Comment: why would you want to put radio button in first activity if it oes nothing there?

Comment: send the current object of that activity to the other activities while they are created. so that u can access all the controls in that activity. note that you hve to set the visibility to public of all controls..

Comment: rahmathullah: can you please explain this with example